# Is it possible to call a function from the standard library if it has been overridden?

Tags: lua

Lua has various functions for manipulating a table such as `table.insert()`. But what if that word has been overridden?

For example:

```
function (table)
end
```

The value of `table` is whatever is passed and I can no longer use the table functions of the standard library which were previously accessible through the global `table` accessor.

Comment: Uh, don't name your parameters like that? :)  If you really want to, you need to save those values with another name outside the function body, i.e. `local TABLE_LIBRARY= table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access globals through the global table `_G`, so in this case you'd just use `_G.table` to access the global `table` object instead of the shadowing function argument.

Comment: What solution you can suggest for `function(_G, table)` ? :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, use `_ENV.table`.

Comment: In that case you could use `_ENV` inside the function. And if `_ENV` is also named as an argument, then the `_ENV` in the argument will shadow the global environment, and your function will effectively be sandboxed by it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Fun but as you probably know, ["As a convention, programs should avoid creating names that start with an underscore followed by one or more uppercase letters"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1).

Comment: @TomBlodget - Yes, _THE_CODE_IS_CONTRIVED, but this task has a solution.  Could you find it?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `debug.getregistry()._LOADED.table` Good example of why you should restrict access to `debug` in a Lua sandbox, I guess.

Comment: @ECrownofFire - Nice!  Now try to find solution which doesn't use debug library.

Answer (score 0):

Who overrode the `table` variable? If you, then first set the original `table` to a different variable:

```
luaTable = table
```

Then, do your reassignment:

```
table = somethingElse
```

You can then access the original `table` functions:

```
luaTable.insert()
```